# How to attach plates (my design) to the stator core of the machine more efficiently and precisely?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, materials, applied-mechanics, mechanical, tools

I am working on an electrical engineering project. However, I have come across a specific mechanical engineering problem. I have attached an image to describe what I want to do. I have primarily a stator core (made out of electrical steel laminated sheets) named part number "1". I have a double-sided adhesive insulation tape named part number "2". Lastly, I have a sheet of electrical steel, which I call a plate, named part number "3". The part number 2 will be put on the inner diameter of part number 1. After that, part number 3 will be put on the inner diameter of part number 1, which already has the part number 2. The part number 3 is made up of multiple strips (as you can see in the figure).
Can you guys tell me the most efficient and precise way of putting these parts together, like I described above? You are welcome to give the suggestions regarding techniques or the tools. You are welcome to ask any follow-up questions.[image]

Comment: Does part number 3 fit in-between part number 2 and 1 ? Also a lot of times when you say inner diameter I think you mean out diameter.

Comment: @SamiSafarini, part number 2 fits in between part numbers 1 and 3. When I am saying the inner diameter of part number 1, I am actually saying it as the inner diameter of part number 1. For your clarification, part number 1 is a Wound Field Synchronous Machine (WFSM) stator core and it has the inner diameter.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I was confused abit by the image.